# Python matplotlib bar graph color

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, graph, bar-chart

I'm trying to display some data in bar graph using xticks. The code below displays my bars in different colors. My question is how do I make the whole graph in one color? Thanks in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = (5)
data_2 = (6)

plt.bar(1, data)
plt.bar(2, data_2)

plt.xticks([1,2], ('Hello', 'World'))

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = (5)
data_2 = (6)

plt.bar([1,2], [data,data_2])

plt.xticks([1,2], ('Tom', 'Dick'))

plt.show()
```

---

Or add `color` keyword argument:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = (5)
data_2 = (6)
color = 'red'
plt.bar(1, data, color=color)
plt.bar(2, data_2, color=color)

plt.xticks([1,2], ('Tom', 'Dick'))

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ann Zen. I did not know by making the items in one list I'd have same colored bars. That is interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is an easier way to obtain the same color for all bars.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2]
x_ticks = ['Tom', 'Dick']
y = [5,6]
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.xticks(x, x_ticks);
```

In case you want to use `pandas`

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2],
                   'y': [5, 6],
                   'name': ['Tom', 'Dick']})

ax = df.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='bar')
ax.set_xticks(df.index)
ax.set_xticklabels(df["name"], rotation=0);
```

or even easier

```py
df.plot(x='name', y='y', kind='bar', rot=0);
```